# Proving a sequence of superiors converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $$\{a_n\}$$ from n=1 to infinite be a sequence of real numbers that is bounded. Define a new sequence $$\{b_n\}$$ from n=1 to infinite by $$b_n =\sup   a_k\text{ when }k\ge n$$

I need to show that the sequence $$\{b_n\}$$ from 1 to infinite is a monotone decreasing sequence. I know the general idea is that I have to prove that the sequence converges to the greatest lower bound, but I'm unsure of how. Basically how do I show that as n goes to infinite, $$\{b_n\}$$ converges. (I also apologize for my horrible coding)

Answer (score 2):

If $b_n=a_n$ then $b_{n+1}\le b_n$. If $b_n\neq a_n$ then $b_{n+1}=b_n$. To sum up, $b_{n+1}\le b_n$. That is, $\{b_n\}$ is decreasing.

Furthermore, $\inf \{a_n\}\le b_n\le\sup\{a_n\}$ and hence the sequence $\{b_n\}$ is bounded.

Since $\{b_n\}$ is a monotonic, bounded sequence, it converges.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you have $$b_n = a_n$$. Since $$b_n$$ is just the superior of $$a_n$$, isn't it possible that they are never equal?